# Installing plugins in vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Am running the command below:-
sudo apt install curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs     https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim

I get this error:-

E: Command line option 'L' [from -fLo] is not understood in combination with the other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt install` and `curl` are entirely different commands. `sudo apt install curl` would install the `curl` program itself, and then you can do `curl -fLo ...`. You should look into what these commands mean before copy pasting them into your terminal and hitting enter.

Comment: The Ubuntu tag is for programming questions specific to Ubuntu. General Ubuntu support is off-topic. Support questions may be asked oat https://askubuntu.com/.